# Префикс в таблицах mysql

Tags: mysql

Для чего  названия таблиц базы данных mysql, как правило, начинаются с префикса? Самый нелепый ответ, который я получил - это "в целях безопасности". А на самом деле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того что в одной базе могут хранится таблицы нескольких сайтов на одном движке(хотя так делать, разумеется, не стоит) или на разных но с совпадающими именами таблиц. Именно для этого и существуют префиксы.

Comment: или несколько движков с одинаковыми названиями таблиц. форум, там, блог еще что-то везде могут быть users...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, да-да, все теперь понятно. Просто я ничего не знаю про большие проекты. Это же только мне на Денвере хватает несколько простых таблиц и все.

Answer (score 2):

Эта практика родилась тогда, когда пятидолларовые хостинги на минимальном тарифе давали достаточно дискового пространства для 7-10 сайтов, но всего 1 БД ;)

Сейчас удобно для разделения таблиц по модулям, но первичная причина именно одна БД